# SQL find max date based on a non null other column

Tags: sql, datetime, greatest-n-per-group, presto, amazon-athena

I have a table like so:

```
|uniqueID|scandatetime       |scanfacilityname|
+--------+-------------------+----------------+
|12345678|01-01-2020 13:45:12|BALTIMORE       |
|12345678|01-02-2020 22:45:12|BALTIMORE       |
|12345678|01-04-2020 10:15:12|PHILADELPHIA    |
|12345678|01-05-2020 08:45:12|                |
```

And I would like to return an entire row containing the uniqueID, scandatetime, and latest scanfacilityname (i.e., max scandatetime where scanfacilityname is not null). I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT
"uniqueID"
, "max"(CAST("scandatetime" AS timestamp)) "timestamp"
, COALESCE("scanfacilityname") "scanfacilityname"
FROM
iv_scans_new.scan_data
WHERE (("partition_0" = '2020') AND ("partition_1" IN ('06', '07', '08'))) and  scanfacilityname is not null
group by 1, 3
;
```

But im not sure if this is correct/if I need the coalesce.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `COALESCE("scanfacilityname")` can be simplified to `"scanfacilityname"`

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: It's Athena/prestodb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `max_by` function:

```
select max_by(uniqueID, scanfacilityname), max_by(scandatetime, scanfacilityname), max(scanfacilityname)
```

See the [doc](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#max_by).

There's no `coalesce` needed since the `max` and `max_by` functions will effectively ignore `null` values.

Comment: The docs explicitly say `max_by` does not ignore nulls "Except for count(), count_if(), max_by(), min_by() and approx_distinct(), all of these aggregate functions ignore null values and return null for no input rows or when all values are null."

Answer (score 0):

One option is to filter with a subquery:

```
select s.*
from iv_scans_new.scan_data s
where s.scandatetime = (
    select max(s1.scandatetime)
    from iv_scans_new.scan_data s1
    where s1.uniqueID = s.uniqueID and s1.scanfacilityname is not null
)
```

You can also use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        s.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by uniqueID order by scandatetime desc) rn
    from iv_scans_new.scan_data s
    where scanfacilityname is not null
) s
where rn = 1
```